# Python module Numpy install

Tags: python

I am using Python 2.5, I just download numpy 1.9.0 from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy.
I am not so sure where should I put the module, hope you can help me.

Comment: Just a tip: use at least Python 2.7 not 2.5; the latter is very, very old and it hardly makes sense to start using it now.

Comment: This really depends on how you downloaded it and on what OS. But this should help explain http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/index.html#building

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extract `numpy` and go to the extracted folder, there should be a `setup.py` file there. Execute `python setup.py install` to install the `numpy` package. While this is the way, I would rather suggest you to use `pip` to install package. Then you should not worry about the dependency.